# Catch FileNotFoundError on imp.reload if the module itself cannot be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.3

I'm working on a dynamic module reloading system (for modules outside my control). It's possible that when we try to reload a module, the module's file has been removed. I would like to catch and specially handle this error. However, `imp.reload()` also executes the module, and that execution could produce unrelated `FileNotFoundError`s, and I do not want to catch these.

Is there a good way to do this? (As the tags state, I am on Python 3.3.)

Comment: I don't believe so. You try a whole statement, so that includes reloading and what happens during it (running the module). If it's your module, consider encapsulating its parts in functions and checking whether it's a script or a module on load (`if __name__ == "__main__:"` to execute stuff when loaded as a script)

Comment: I'm reloading arbitrary third-party modules, so I can't do that. I've updated the question.